# Java Eclipse UTF-8 Hanzi Character Issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, character, println

I am working with a `Scanner` object and a few Chinese Hanzi characters to be displayed and processed as input.

They appear from a `println` perfectly, but as I attempt to enter them for me `scanner.next()` call they simply change the color of the `System.out.println` output above and cause the program to lock up OR the scanner to stop accepting input upon <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the right charset in the [Scanner constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) ?

> ```
> public Scanner(InputStream source,
>                String charsetName)
> ```
>
> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted into characters using the specified charset.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>            source - An input stream to be scanned
>       charsetName - The encoding type used to convert bytes from the stream 
>                     into characters to be scanned
> ```